# How to use web3.eth.getTransaction() with infura, or is there any alternative to replace infura?

Tags: web3js, contract-deployment, metamask, ropsten, infura

I tried to deploy my contract on Ropsten TestNet with infura and web3.js, however when I used some functions it returned 405 error.
I notice that maybe I could not use web3.eth.getTransaction() when infura, however when I use following script

    `<script src="./node_modules/web3/dist/web3.min.js"></script>`

this function is called several times.

How can Iavoid the error, do I need to modity web3.min.js (https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/develop/dist/web3.min.js)? 
Or is there any way to replace infura?

Comment: Post your code for calling ``web3.eth.getTransaction(...)``

Comment: The code is in web3js https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/develop/dist/web3.min.js I just wonder whether I should change it if I want to use infura

Comment: He means, post the code you use to call this function

Answer (score 1):

A 405 means that the underlying JSON-RPC method is not allowed. Most of the methods that are not allowed do not make sense for a service like Infura (e.g. we don't store keys on our servers).

Answer (score 0):

developer advocate at [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com/) here!

I just found this and thought I could add an update here in case someone will need this!

When using `web3.js`, make sure to install it and import it correctly.

> Note that Ropsten and Rinkeby are considered deprecated. I recommend using Goerli instead. Check out this [article about the merge](https://chainstack.com/merge-a-step-by-step-guide-for-developers/) where you can find which testnets are deprecated!

### Install web3.js

Install it with `npm` or `Yarn`, you can reference the [web3.js docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.7/getting-started.html) too.

##### NPM

```bash
npm install web3
```

##### Yarn

```bash
yarn add web3
```

### Import web3.js in your script

Then import it in your script at the top.

```js
const Web3 = require("web3");
```

### eth_getTransaction example

Now you are ready to query the blockchain using `web3.js`; the following script is an example using the `eth_getTransaction` method.

```js
const Web3 = require("web3");
const node_url = "CHAINSTACK_NODE_URL";
const web3 = new Web3(node_url);
web3.eth.getTransaction("0xf915903ecc67ab20a5162ae13eec36e3a68ca558765ada1779847e0a0c35479c", (err, tx) => {
    console.log(tx)
})
```

this will return:

```bash
{
  blockHash: '0xd233ac25d1bd643ce5170cd557e0206b7bd2ece3352fa5edaec3181ac0668fc4',
  blockNumber: 14831527,
  from: '0x31cA75bA3DB4A8A61304dFAa854Bd301Dbc3484d',
  gas: 21000,
  gasPrice: '82115541266',
  maxFeePerGas: '115650024606',
  maxPriorityFeePerGas: '1500000000',
  hash: '0xf915903ecc67ab20a5162ae13eec36e3a68ca558765ada1779847e0a0c35479c',
  input: '0x',
  nonce: 41,
  to: '0xd5E72C75C3d4bAFdb62Dee079d2bF9ef614125B6',
  transactionIndex: 371,
  value: '30000000000000000',
  type: 2,
  accessList: [],
  chainId: '0x1',
  v: '0x1',
  r: '0x313004f2935447fc7d4584beecc3bafaf44231346f57c0b74b14770eddecfd98',
  s: '0x7ad1056eff0c2d12bfb78b85776326a4d5c5ba07d598576e8c2073929b456861'
}
```

Find more code examples in the [Ethereum API section](https://docs.chainstack.com/api/ethereum/ethereum-api-reference#start-building-on-ethereum-using-the-json-rpc-ethereum-api) of the Chainstack docs.

If you wish to try different node providers try [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com/). We support many [EMV-based protocols](https://chainstack.com/protocols/).

1. [Sign up with Chainstack](https://console.chainstack.com/user/account/create).
2. [Deploy a node](https://docs.chainstack.com/platform/join-a-public-network).
3. [View node access and credentials](https://docs.chainstack.com/platform/view-node-access-and-credentials).